# Uniting Putty with WSL-Ansible under the same private key and passphrase

Tags: ssh, putty, automation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ansible

In my PC I use Windows 10 home with WSL-Ubuntu (16.04 - xenial) and Ansible.

I often rent [IaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_service) machines and SSH into them via Putty from Win 10 and all of my IaaS machines are usually orchestrated, installed, configured and continuously upgraded via Ansible with the very same LAMP constellations.

### My problem

The one thing that is a tiny bit annoying to me with Putty is that each time I reboot my PC (say due to some rare Windows 10 upgrade that requires a reboot) I need to load my key with Pageant again to and also executing its passphrase.

**I'd like to avoid a situation were I do it twice** - once for Putty and secondce for Ansible.

### My question

Is there a way to unite Putty and and Ansible together under Pageant (and also, on the way make Pageant to boot together with my PC? I didn't find a way to autostart it with the PC from `msconfig` or task manager).

Comment: You need a single sign on solution like this: https://www.ansible.com/blog/red-hat-single-sign-on-integration-with-ansible-tower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set Pageant to automatically load all keys on startup.
Pageant can load one or more private keys when it starts up,
if you provide them on the Pageant command line.

Do this:

- Open the Windows 10 startup folder in explorer:
  `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.
- Right-click inside the folder and select *New > Shortcut*
- Browse to the PuTTY installation, for example "C:\Program Files\PuTTY",
  and select "pageant.exe"
- Give the shortcut a name
- Right-click the newly created shortcut and select *Properties*
- If you have only one private key, append its full path to *Target* field like:

  ```
  "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pageant.exe" "C:\Path\to\myKeys\MyKey.ppk"
  ```
- For multiple keys, to avoid the line becoming too long,
  set the *Start in* folder to the one containing your keys,
  perhaps
  "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\myKeys", and then only the key file-names need to
  be specified, as in:

  ```
  "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\Pageant.exe" key1.ppk key2.ppk key3.ppk
  ```

Source:
[Making Pageant automatically load keys on startup](https://blog.shvetsov.com/2010/03/making-pageant-automatically-load-keys.html).

Comment: Dear Harry (who once helped me amazingly with a very hard router problem), I edited the question --- I fimrly shortened it. I think your answer still applies. I should learn the subject by your answer, I am being hard to concentrate in these hours as I arrange things for a flight and relocation but will do so ASAP.